# pass parameter with resource route to controller laravel

Tags: arrays, laravel, controller, routes, resources

i have resource route like this

```
Route::resource('users','UsersController');
```

and i want to pass array and variables to index page or create page 
so i need it to be like this

```
Route::resource('users','UsersController')-> with array to use it in the functions; // with array passed
```

and use it in my controller like this

```
public function index()
{
   return $my_array_passed_from_route;
    if(Gate::allows('users.view'))
    {
        $users = User::withTrashed()->paginate(100);
        return view('users.index',compact('users'));
    }
    else
        return Helper::not_auth();
}
```

thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should try the code below

```
Route::get('users/{id}', [
'as' => 'users.show',
'uses' => 'UsersController@show'
]);
Route::resource('user', 'UsersController', ['except' => 'show']);
```

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/pass-parameter-to-resource-controller

Comment: Would have been nice if there was a one liner for this.